# IEnumerable from LINQToSQL, where data is stored before/ and during iteration / .NET

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, ienumerable, iqueryable

I have read a lot of questions/answers here , but I don´t get it.

In case you are using LINQtoSQL

```
IEnumerable<Car> CarsInSale= context.Cars.Where(x=> x.Model=="Ferrari");

foreach(Car car in CarsInSale)
    Console.WriteLine("Car:" + car.Price);
```

Imagine the query fecthes around 1000 cars in the CarsInSale variable. 
I want to know what happens in memory inside the app running the query:

- A) Until foreach line, memory usage remains unaffected , right? (defered execution)
- B) Once foreach call is done, all the cars are stored in memory? If answer is NO, where the cars are placed? because it has to be somewhere. I imagine each foreach loop don't hit the database...but give some light here please.
- C) Imagine I am wrong in point B. Each foreach loop hits the database, isn't that so inefficient if the database has some kind of delay (a lots of round trips)? wouln't be much better to retrieve all the data at once and store it in memory?

Many thanks, you are awesome.

Comment: _"I imagine each foreach loop don't hit the database"_ That's wrong, every `foreach` will hit the database and read the cars. If you'd use `context.Cars.Where(x=> x.Model=="Ferrari").ToList()` you would store them in memory. Otherwise that's just the query to retrieve the cars. If one foreach uses `foreach(Car car in CarsInSale.Take(10))` and another `Take(1000)` both would generate a little different sql query(`TOP 10` and `TOP 1000`).

Comment: So LinqToSql IEnumerables are kind of pointer to the Database? Is that the reasons is much more efficient to use IEnumerable instead of List directly?

Comment: Yes, because actually they are `IQueryable<T>`.  But not "pointers" to the database. They just store what you want to select and they know how to translate this to sql.

Comment: I dont get how the IEnumerator has direct connection to the SQL Table and it can be efficient. See point C) please

Comment: The context has the connection to the database. Of course it's inefficient if you had multiple foreach loops and you would always enumerate all cars in the table. Nothing stops you from storing it in a collection before or select only part of it(`Take(100)`) and use that. But sometimes you always need the current snapshot of the database. You could also store this query in a method or property and the public methods that return the cars from your class `Car` would return a list: `return GetFerraris().ToList();`.

Comment: Understand a LINQ query that is not materialized with a method that encapsulates a sql-query and returns a `SqlDataReader` which enables to stream the records. It's up to you what you do with it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter you deserves a beer

Comment: In EntityFramework it's called LINQ to Entities not LINQ To SQL which is an obsolete provider.